# Elements in Fragment not working after re-adding the same fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-appcompat

## **UPDATE**: I have found the header isn't the only thing affected, but `listeners` and other elements in the fragment aren't being initialized.  (Such as FAB's).  The only things that function correctly is anything built inside the `adapter` (i.e. the `ListView` rows)

**The Problem**:  Open Nav Drawer, click on a list item that opens up a new `Fragment` in the same `Activity`.  Open the Nav Drawer again, click the same item that should simply replace the existing `Fragment` and while the `Fragment` does open, all of the elements that are set programmatically in Java (text, colors, listeners) are not changed/added to the `Fragment`.  The view is simply the default `xml` layout.  I have confirmed with `Log.d` that the code that sets these things *is* being ran. (If you open a different `Fragment` and then go back to the original one, everything works fine)

**The Confirmed Cause:**  When changing this:

```
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1"
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
```

to

```
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
```

(if only one of these libraries is changed, it doesn't matter which one, the problem still occurs)

I have confirmed changing these two libraries is the problem (also confirmed this problem in a second app -- and changing *only* this code, has the exact same result)

**My questions is**, why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

**The Code and more detailed description from original question:**

```
                FragmentTransaction tItems = fm.beginTransaction();
                ListFragment mFrag = new PlannerFragment();
                tItems.replace(R.id.main_frag, mFrag, TAG_CALC_FRAGMENT);
                tItems.commit();
```

There are about 4 options in my drawer that all open this Fragment, but before each one, I set a global variable like this:

```
MyApp.PlanType = "highbal";
MyApp.PlanType = "lowbal";
etc.
```

Based on the `PlanType` value (above), that `Fragment` is loaded with different data (but, in the exact same xml layouts). It is simply a `ListView` with a header.

This `Fragment`, (`PlannerFragment`) loads fine the first time.

When I click on another item (a different `PlanType`) that goes to the same `Fragment` (same code above executed):  The `ListView` loads fine in the actual list.  **But** in the `header` in the list, none of the `setText()` values set the new data properly.  It uses the default values from my `xml` layout.

Now, if I load a different `Fragment` in between, everything works great.  It's only when I either add or replace (I've tried both) the same `Fragment` on top of the old one does this happen.

Here is header code at top of `PlannerFragment`

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Setup listview
        lv = getListView();

        LayoutInflater inflaterHeader = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflaterHeader.inflate(R.layout.planner_listview_header, lv, false);
        lv.addHeaderView(header, null, false);

        // Load Data then Set Textviews, e.g.:
        TextView title = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvPlannerTitle);
    dateOutput = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvDebtOutDate);
```

If I add to that code, `dateOutput.setText("test");` it does not happen.  I can do a `Log.d`and my data registers, so this code is being read, but the UI is not set.

I've even tried removing the `Fragment` first like this with a check:

```
                Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_CALC_FRAGMENT);
                if(fragment != null)
                    fm.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
```

This has no effect.

Again, this ONLY happened when I changed the libraries above.  Is this a bug with the library or does it now respond differently?

Comment: try calling `ft.executePendingTransactions()` after `tItems.commit();`

Comment: @OlegBogdanov  I did a `fm.executePendingTransactions();` right after the line you said and I end up with the same result.

Comment: please update your question and put your fragment's `onCreateView`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is many **changes and issues with Fragments on appcompat 25.1.0**. The first one seems related to your issue but the two next should be read as it may be important.

---

#### FragmentTransaction replace behaviour

**Replace not working properly in appCompat 25.1.0**
**Current status** (Jan 4 2017): bug **assigned**
[Issue link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=%20230526&)

---

#### Fragment lifecycle change on 25.1.0

**onStart on new Fragment is called before onStop on previous one**
**Current Status** : works as expected. For me it could be a breaking change from app compat 25.0.x
[Issue link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230415)

There is also an issue with the **resume event called two times** in fragment, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230554&q=25.1.0&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened).

**TLDR.** Maybe the best temporary solution is to not use 25.1.0 until a new version is out.

Comment: I had a strong sense this was a bug in the library. Thanks for confirming this.

Comment: The number of bugs, with similar severity to those mentioned above, in the last few Support Library upgrades has been pretty disappointing; thanks for the links though @Hugo

Answer (score 3):

you can add `list_view_header.xml` in `navigationDrawer()` method and change the position of  selected item like `selectItem(position - 1)`.

```
  private void navigationDrawer() {

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        // mNavigationDrawerItemTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View listHeaderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_header, null, false);
        mDrawerList.addHeaderView(listHeaderView, null, false);

        setupToolbar();

        DataModel[] drawerItem = new DataModel[6];

        drawerItem[0] = new DataModel(R.drawable.dashboard_icon, "Dashboard");
        drawerItem[1] = new DataModel(R.drawable.cal_icon, "Calender");
        drawerItem[2] = new DataModel(R.drawable.classes, "Classes");
        drawerItem[3] = new DataModel(R.drawable.message_icon_hdpi, "Message Center");
        drawerItem[4] = new DataModel(R.drawable.profile, "Profile & Setting");
        drawerItem[5] = new DataModel(R.drawable.bulletin_icon, "Bulletin Board");

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_item_row, drawerItem);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        setupDrawerToggle();


    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position - 1);
        }


    }

    private void selectItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Fragment_DashBoard();
                // toolbar.setTitle("Dashboard");
                Titletv.setText("Dashboard");
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Fragment_Calender();
                // toolbar.setTitle("Calender");
                Titletv.setText("Calender");

                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Fragment_Classes();
                // toolbar.setTitle("Classes");
                Titletv.setText("Classes");
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new Fragment_MessageCenter();
                // toolbar.setTitle("Message");
                Titletv.setText("Messages");
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new Fragment_ProfileSetting();
                // toolbar.setTitle("Profile");
                Titletv.setText("Profile");

                break;

            case 5:
                fragment = new Fragment_BulletinBoard();
                //toolbar.setTitle("Bulletin Board");
                Titletv.setText("Bulletin Board");

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }


        if (fragment != null) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction trans = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(i, true);
            mDrawerList.getItemAtPosition(i);
            // setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);


        } else {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }


    }
```